# selection Menu like Tap Tap Revenge 3

Tags: iphone, custom-component

I am wondering how to achieve selection menu like tap tap revenge 3 have.Do I need to make a whole custom class or any help which class should I drive my subclass.I tried to modify UIPickerView but I cant change background image and frame(both is private).

Thanks
Mrigank Gupta

Here is the link of image(not having reputation to post image)

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/345aed3aee.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Making a custom control class will be easier than trying to shoehorn one of the existing ones.

Tapbots put together a little article on their work. 
http://tapbots.com/blog/design/designing-convertbot

You should be able to use a few images, a button, graphics transforms and touch event handling to pull it off.